# Speed Up website by reducing css files

Tags: css, performance, file

I'm wondering about css files

let's say that we have about 8 css files

here is my question

is it better to put my css code in my html file to reduce css files requests

or putting all my 8 css files in one css file

Comment: Combine all of your 8 CSS files into 1 single CSS file and then minify it using some online service like CSS Minifier (http://cssminifier.com/).

Comment: what about adding my css code in my html file ?

Comment: Not recommended at all, that'll adversely effect the speed of your website.

Comment: Putting CSS in your HTML file will only make it less maintainable. There is no speed benefit to doing so (and in fact, may make it slower since you can't take advantage of parallel HTTP requests that way).

Comment: Put all in one, minifiy and then gzip on your server. My 87kb is now 15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put them in one CSS file and minify the file. Computer technology is now so fast that the CSS request speed won't be affected that much. You will reap more benefits doing it that way than putting the CSS in your html

Comment: There are several compilers out there these days that will handle this for you in a production environment, as well.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to CSS, multiple files will not slow down your website (in a way that you can notice a difference), but they can make your code much nicer and better organsized. In my opinion it is good to split your CSS files into two main categories:

- main CSS file for website layout
- secondary CSS files for some specific elements, rarerly used (e.g. spinner that appears only on home page)

This approach will also make it easier to reuse the code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a pro in WordPress, when I use SEO checker, my website https://nsplomodiern.lite-heberg.fr have 4 CSS files. I wanted to minify it to have only one file.
Anybody have a step by step tutorial to help?

Thanks a lot!
[Seo css analytics results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PD6el.jpg)